# Does a Dask scheduler effectively occupy one CPU core? What local resources are assigned to the scheduler?

Tags: parallel-processing, scheduler, dask, worker

Suppose I have a machine with :
4 CPU (s):
2 Thread (s) per core
2 Core (s) per socket
1 CPU Socket (s)

If I set a Dask-scheduler and 4 workers doing dask-worker with `--nprocs 4` from the Dask Dashboard, I can see that is assigned a core and 1/4 of the total memory I have on the machine to each worker.

> I don't understand what resources of the local machine are actually assigned to the scheduler ?

Before this check, I would have said that by default to the scheduler is assigned a core but it doesn't seem true to me now.

Comment: Would you mind to update your post with a copy of the output from a call to `hwloc`-tool: **`lstopo-no-graphics -.ascii`**? Hardware conditions matter.

Answer (score 0):

The Dask scheduler is single-threaded, and so will generally occupy at most one thread.

To be clear though, it isn't allocated anything and there aren't any hard restrictions on it.  The Dask scheduler is a normal Python process.